# Polymer voice input element or script

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, voice-recognition

I am creating a mobile application. I was wondering if it is possible to make a voice input like ok google.

I found a script https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API but I've no idea how I can integrate this script in polymer way.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a kind-of-old github project that uses the Web Speech API. https://github.com/zenorocha/voice-elements

Comment: If you are willing to use Polymer 2, there are the new [app-media](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-media) elements which allow you to access media devices such as microphones and cameras.

Comment: My bad, turns out these do actually support Polymer 1.8+